# Saving 2D-array (matrix) to a binary inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, matrix

I am basically trying to save a large 2D-array (matrix) in a function as a binary.

As it is now (see first toy code below) the matrix is converted to a pointer to the first element in each row(?). This is emphasized by the warning `fwrite` inside the function `saveToFile`:

Size of array function parameter will return size of `"int(*)[4]"`instead of `"int[3][4]"`

I got around the problem by defining the matrix through `rows*cols`.

I wonder if there is a simple way that I can pass the matrix as an array of arrays instead of a set of pointers pointing at the beginning of arrays such that I can save and upload the matrix as convenient as I did in the main program (see last toy code).

That is, does it exist a way to circumvent the need for `rows*cols` in `fwrite` and `fread`?

Grateful for all input.

First toy code:

```
# define rows 3
# define cols 4

void saveToFile(int matrix[rows][cols]){

FILE * fout = fopen("test.dat", "wb");                 // save
fwrite(matrix, sizeof(matrix), rows*cols, fout);
fclose(fout);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int m1[rows][cols];
int m2 [rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        m1[i][j]= i+j;
    }
}
saveToFile(m1);

FILE * fin = fopen("test.dat", "rb");                   // open
fread(m2, sizeof(m2), rows*cols, fin);
fclose(fin);

return 0;
}
```

Second toy code:

```
# define rows 3
# define cols 4

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int m1[rows][cols];
int m2 [rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        m1[i][j]= i+j;
    }
}

FILE * fout = fopen("test.dat", "wb");     // save
fwrite(m1, sizeof(m1), 1, fout);
fclose(fout);


FILE * fin = fopen("test.dat", "rb");      // open
fread(m2, sizeof(m2), 1,  fin);
fclose(fin);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(matrix)` will always be the pointer size. I don't think there's a way around that in C. In C++ you could probably have a template function

Comment: Sorry, arrays are passed as pointers in C.  You could use a #define, or have the size of the matrix be an argument to the function.  Also, in your code you want sizeof(**matrix), you just must happen to be on a system where sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have corrected the original code to sizeof(*matrix). Again thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I hope you'll enjoy my solution, just as much as I enjoyed while finding it right now.

You see, the problem is, you are passing the pointer `m1` to the function `saveToFile`. You know what happens when you pass things; an equivalent size of memory location is allocated for that argument to be held, memory location is filled with a copy of the value the argument has. In the end, it is just a copy. For example;

```
void asd( int qwe ) {
    qwe = 5;
}

int main( ) {
    int qwe = 1;
    asd( qwe );

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `qwe` inside `main` isn't changed, the `qwe` inside `asd` isn't the same as in `main`.

You cannot expect, at least in C, for an array as a whole to be copied with single operation. In your *first toy* thing, just a copy of the pointer is sent. Programme, naturally, may not know about what the original was. Well, actually it could possibly, since you specify both the amount of rows and columns, but whatever, it can't.

### Here's the solution:

You won't pass the `m1`, but the address of `m1`, that is `&m1`. You'll hand in just a copy of the address, and from that address, you'll access the actual and original variable `m1` from the other function. Like this:

```
void saveToFile( int (* matrix)[rows][cols] ) {
    // matrix as a pointer to a 2D array of integers
    printf( "%d\n", sizeof * matrix );
}

int main( ) {
    int m1[rows][cols];
    printf( "%d\n", sizeof m1 );
    saveToFile( &m1 );  // passing the address of m1
}
```

Drawback: You'll have to enclose each reference to the `matrix` with parenthesis and precede with an asterisk, whenever you want to access an element. But this does what I think you want it to do.

Made me also learn something, something that I already knew, actually... Just wasn't that so aware of.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Thx :) I got it to work now.

Comment: Passing the pointer works, but when I try to read the file the program crashes.

Comment: @userjuicer Well, that was not the question, so I did not check anything further... There is one mistake there in your code, beyond this fix I've offered: You shouldn't pass `sizeof( matrix )`, `m1`, `m2`, etc. as the second argument for `fwrite` and `fread` functions. The second argument takes the size of an individual element in the stream you push in with the first argument. So they should be `sizeof( m1[0][0] )` for example. And if you have applied the `&` and `*` fix I've offered here, then your `fwrite` call's second argument should be `sizeof( (*matrix)[0][0] )`, and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

`fread` and `fwrite` wont fit for your task. Instead use `fprintf` and `fscanf`:

```
int main(){
    FILE *fin = NULL, *fout = NULL;
    int c, i = 0, j = 0;
    int m1[rows][cols];
    int m2[rows][cols];

    fout = fopen("test.dat", "wb");
    if(fout == NULL){printf("Error reading file \n"); return 0;}

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            m1[i][j]= i+j;
            fprintf(fout, "%d\n", m1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fout);

    fin = fopen("test.dat", "rb"); 
    if(fin == NULL){printf("Error reading file \n"); return 0;}

    i = j = 0;
    while( (c = fscanf(fin, "%d", &m2[i][j])) != EOF ){
        j++;
        if(j == cols ){i++; j = 0;}
        if(i == rows){break;}
    }

    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit

```
void saveToFile(int *matrix){
    FILE *fout = fopen("test.dat", "wb"); // save

    fwrite(matrix, sizeof(matrix), rows*cols, fout);

    fclose(fout);
}

or

void saveToFile(int **matrix){
    FILE *fout = fopen("test.dat", "wb"); // save

    fwrite(matrix, sizeof(matrix), rows*cols, fout);

    fclose(fout);
}
```

and call it

```
saveToFile(&m1[0][0]); //prototype void saveToFile(int *);

or

saveToFile(m1); //prototype void saveToFile(int **);
```

the fread should be:

```
fread(m2, sizeof(**m2), rows*cols, fin);
```

valter

Comment: Now I am confused. You mean in the second toy example? I just ran that program and it works…?

Comment: @userjuicer Yes, like your second toy. I can do it calling a function(like your first toy) but it was faster for me to write the code.

Comment: Just explains to me what is wrong with the previous method. I have ran toy example 2 many times with large matrixes and it has worked. But when I try ThoAppelsins solution the data becomes corrupt/ program crashes for some reason

Comment: @userjuicer What is the *previous method*? Yours or mine?

Comment: Second toy code have been run on 2000x50 matrixes many times without any problem. but as I said when I use write fread I get the dat files become corrupted when I create them in a function according to ThoAppelsin